# command to find all jobs running for more than 10 minutes

Tags: python, bash

I am wanting to run a script that will renice all running jobs that have been on for more than 10 CPU minutes. Any suggestions how to do this. So, I guess this will involve listing all jobs running for more than 10 minutes and then issuing the command

```
for i in pidlist 
   do 
     renice $i
done
```

But how do I get the pidlist?

Thanks!

Edit: I am trying the following as root:

```
ps  -e -o pid,uid,nice,cputime= | awk '{gsub(/:/, "", $4); if (($1 > 1024) && ($2 >= 1000) && ($4 > 10) && ($3 <= 0)) print}'
```

and I get the following list:

```
1679 1000 0 230641
```

But, without the conditioning, here is what I get:

```
ps  -e -o pid,uid,nice,cputime= | awk '{gsub(/:/, "", $4); if (($2 >= 1000) && ($4 > 0) && ($3 <= 0)) print}'
```

and I get:

```
  1499 1000 0 000000
1501 1000 0 000000
1504 1000 0 000015
1529 1001 0 002238
1531 1000 0 000000
1532 1000 0 000000
1603 1000 0 000000
1607 1000 0 000000
1653 1000 0 000001
1667 1000 0 000000
1669 1000 0 000001
1672 1000 0 003817
1673 1000 0 000004
1675 1000 0 000000
1677 1000 0 000000
1678 1000 0 035431
1679 1000 0 230641
1694 1000 -11 000003
1716 1000 0 000000
1745 1000 0 000001
1748 1000 0 000006
1792 1000 0 000000
1983 1001 0 002207
2744 1000 0 000000
2745 1000 0 000010
2746 1000 0 000014
2747 1000 0 000000
2748 1000 0 000000
2876 1000 0 000000
2968 1000 0 000000
3111 1001 0 000000
3120 1001 0 000000
3614 1000 0 000010
3615 1000 0 000000
3616 1000 0 000000
3624 1000 0 000000
4326 1000 0 000000
4328 1000 0 000000
5574 1000 0 000001
5575 1000 0 000000
5576 1000 0 000000
6631 1000 0 034310
7729 1000 0 000002
9358 1001 0 001215
9453 1001 0 001212
11437 1001 0 000000
11971 1000 0 000000
13508 1001 0 000134
15130 1001 0 003458
16713 1000 0 000000
16715 1000 0 000043
20105 1001 0 000004
20111 1001 0 000021
22670 1000 0 000000
23496 1000 0 000000
23526 1000 0 000000
23865 1001 0 000755
24137 1001 0 000003
25023 1001 0 000631
25057 1001 0 000626
25660 1001 0 000538
26310 1001 0 000104
26354 1001 0 000441
26506 1000 0 000000
26724 1001 0 000411
26802 1000 0 000000
27071 1001 0 000041
```

Some of these processes clearly satisfy the condition. Then why does it not show up? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks again!
    27082 1001 0 003040
    27426 1001 0 000317
    29626 1001 0 002744
    31705 1001 0 002531
    32090 1000 0 000008
    32091 1000 0 000000
    32092 1000 0 000000
    32760 1001 0 000040

Comment: 10 minutes wall clock time or 10 minutes of CPU usage?

Comment: edited -- 10 CPU minutes.

Comment: Dumb question: why not use a cron job?

Comment: Smartypants: would cron job not come across the same issue? You still need to list all running jobs that have been on for more than 10 CPU minutes. Unless you have some other idea that I don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `ps` to get not only the time but also if the job has already been `nice`d. In addition, you probably don't want to mess with low-numbered processes. As larsks mentions above, `awk` is a good tool for processing the column-based output from `ps`:

```
# get the output from ps; setting column name to empty string suppresses header
ps -e -o pid= -o cputime= -o nice= |
# replace the colons so time is a plain number; omit system and already nice processes 
awk '{gsub(/:/, "", $2); time = $2 + 0; if ($1 > 1024 && time > 1000 && $3 <= 0) print $1}' |
# renice the ones left
xargs renice +10
```

Comment: Thanks! What does the $1 > 1024 do?

Comment: Also, I tried:   ps -e -o pid= -o cputime= -o nice= | awk '{gsub(/:/, "", $2); if ($1 > 1000 && $2 > 1000 && $3 <= 10) print $1}' to see what is printed out and I got only 1 PID (which is not even the job) when there are at least 20 jobs running. So this does not seem to be doing what I want.

Comment: `$1 > 1024` makes sure you're not looking at kernel processes with low PID. `$2 > 1000` is checking the user time is more than 10:00, and `$3 <= 0` is looking for PID with niceness of zero or less. Works fine for me.

Comment: Trying again:    ps ax -e -o pid,uid,nice,cputime= | awk '{gsub(/:/, "", $4); if (($1 > 1024) && ($1 >= 1000) && ($4 > 1000) && ($3 <= 0)) print $1}'   
gives me only the longest running process and that is it.Strange! Even replacing the $4 > 1000 with $4 > 1 gives me the same process. However, changing the inequality the other way gives me all the other processes. No idea what is wrong.

Comment: You must be typoing something, cause I've tried on 2 Linux boxes and a Mac, `awk` returns a list of PIDs just fine.

Comment: OK, I will edit my question and you can see if there is an error. (I am just copying what I am writing.)

Comment: You can try with the edit I just made, to explicitly cast the time to an integer. But, as I said, I can't reproduce the problems you're having.

Comment: Explicitly casting the time to an integer fixes the problem, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Is there something I can add to the answer to make it worth an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I get the pidlist?

Read through `man ps` and see the various format options here.  Based on the documentation, something like this will get you a list of process ids and their corresponding CPU time:

```
ps -e -o pid= -o cputime=
```

Run that through `awk` and you should have the list you're looking for.

Comment: I see, so essentially list all jobs and then using string-processing (awk) to get rid of those above 00:10:00. Wil try and get back to you, thanks!